# Changing a python button color using customtkinter to red then back to original value does unexpected things

Tags: python, button, pycharm, customtkinter

I have a button that I'd like to change when it is clicked, then after code is ran it changes back to the default color.  I can get it to change color using the following code.  Since I don't have the stepper motor in yet I can't run the code for it to move so I just use a time.sleep to simulate it.

Before the button is pressed

[image: Before button press]

After the button is pressed

[image]

So far so good.  Now if I uncomment the time.sleep line, the color doesn't change until the sleep is completed, not sure why.

If I uncomment the `self.button_11.configure(fg_color=['#3B8ED0','#1F6AA5'])` line, regardless of the sleep command being commented out or not, the color never changes to red.

I'm expecting the following:

1. Button fg_color = blueish before click
2. When the button is clicked the button color becomes red
3. 5 seconds pass
4. The button returns to it's normal fg_color

I have no idea why the second color immediately overrides the red color.

Any ideas?

```
#   Test the feeder
    def feed_testing(self):
        global feed_steps
        print(self.button_11.cget("fg_color"))
        self.button_11.configure(fg_color="Red")
        print(self.button_11.cget("fg_color"))
#        time.sleep(5)
#        self.button_11.configure(fg_color=['#3B8ED0','#1F6AA5'])
#        print(self.button_11.cget("fg_color"))
```

UPDATE:
I just changed the code to

```
    def feed_testing(self):
        global feed_steps
        print(self.button_11.cget("fg_color"))
        self.button_11.configure(fg_color="Red")
        print(self.button_11.cget("fg_color"))
        self.button_11.update_idletasks()
        time.sleep(5)
#        self.button_11.configure(fg_color=['#3B8ED0','#1F6AA5'])
        self.button_11.configure(fg_color='#3B8ED0')
        print(self.button_11.cget("fg_color"))
```

as described by jasonharper.  Now after the `time.sleep(5)` the button flashes red for a microsecond, just long enough to see it flash.

Comment: While your code is executing `time.sleep()`, it is *not* executing anything else - such as display updates.  Put a `<some widget>.update_idletasks()` just before that to allow the update to happen.  And is a list of two colors actually valid as a `fg_color` value?  I've never seen that before.

Comment: I also thought it was a little weird to have two colors.  CTkButton direct from the customtinker website says "fg_color forground color, tuple: (light_color, dark_color) or single color or "transparent".  I figured that the update would happen with the print command.

Comment: Ok, I'm not a CTk user, so wasn't aware of that option.  But if they explicitly specify a tuple for the option, perhaps a list won't work?

Comment: Not sure, the output of the output of the print statement is ['#3B8ED0', '#1F6AA5'].

Comment: Just tried the update_idletasks() and it did nothing.  I do see in the debugger that the fg_color is red.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, figured it out.  I used `self.button_11.after(1, self.update())` it it worked exactly as needed.

Here's the modified code that works.  Thanks to all who answered, specifically jasonharper. :)

```
#   Test the feeder
    def feed_testing(self):
        global feed_steps
        print(self.button_11.cget("fg_color"))
        self.button_11.configure(fg_color="Red")
        self.button_11.after(1, self.update())
        print(self.button_11.cget("fg_color"))
        time.sleep(5)
        self.button_11.configure(fg_color=['#3B8ED0','#1F6AA5'])
        print(self.button_11.cget("fg_color"))
```